# Convert "Data URIs" to "Web URLs"

Tags: javascript, url, svg, png, uri

I need a way to automatically convert a "data uri" (from a **.png** or a **.svg** file) to a web url.

So I need a way to convert this :
`data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`
To this
`https://www.example.com/blablabla`

Where `blablabla` contains all the informations of the data uri. And I need an automatic way (not a website that does it for me case by case).

Thank you!

*I have researched in so many websites...*

Comment: If you do a google search on images, the thumbs they are using are all data:uri-s. Do a right click on the thumb, oppen it in a new tab and you will see the url: a "data:uri"

Comment: What do you mean by a "web url". Can you give us an example of such, like `https://www.example.com/blablabla`? Just add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to 'automatically' convert, I'm assuming you mean that you want a server to host the files and write a script for the conversion. Since you're using JS, you can utilize Node.js w/ Express. Here's a basic template you can use:

> npm install express uuid

```
// Import required libraries
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

// Initialize express application
const app = express();
// Enable JSON request parsing
app.use(express.json());

// Define the directory for storing uploaded files
const UPLOAD_DIR = '/path/to/upload/dir';

// Serve static files from the upload directory
app.use(express.static(UPLOAD_DIR));


// Define a lookup table for MIME types to file extensions instead of having a long list of 'if' branches
const MIME_TYPES = {
    'image/png': '.png',
    'image/svg+xml': '.svg',
    // Add more MIME types as needed
};

// Define route for file upload
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    // Extract data URI from the request
    const dataUri = req.body.dataUri;
    // Split data URI into header and data parts
    const [header, encoded] = dataUri.split(',');
    // Convert base64 encoded data into a buffer
    const data = Buffer.from(encoded, 'base64');

    // Extract MIME type from header and look up file extension
    const mimeType = header.split(';')[0].split(':')[1];
    const extension = MIME_TYPES[mimeType];

    // Generate a unique file name and construct the file path
    const fileName = uuidv4() + extension;
    const filePath = path.join(UPLOAD_DIR, fileName);

    // Write data to file
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, data);

    // Construct URL to the file and send it in the response
    const url = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/${fileName}`;
    res.json({ url });
});

// Start the server
app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 5000');
});
```

Here, you send a POST to `/upload` using JSON containing the URI, which is decoded and returned as a URL.

Run with:

> node filenamehere.js

And use this for accepting:

> http://localhost:5000/upload

Make sure to:

- Replace the path with your desired path
- Run this in the correct dir
- Ensure that the URIs are valid - otherwise this will not work
- Add authentication if you're scared about others uploading files to your server

Comment: First at all, the first step doesn't work. I launch "npm install express uuid" in my CMD window, but there is an error.